# How do I prove that $a\vec{v}=0$ if $a=0$ or $\vec{v}=0$ (where $a$ is a scalar and $\vec{v}$ is a vector)?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors, matrix-equations

I can prove that $a=0$ or $\textbf{v}=0$ if $a$$\textbf{v}=\textbf{0}$, but not the converse of that statement. *How would I go about proving that?*

Answer (score 1):

If $a = 0$, then

$av = 0v = (0 + 0)v = 0v + 0v$

That seems about right; now we take the leftmost and rightmost bits to write

$av = 0v + 0v = av + av$.

We conclude with $av = av + av \iff av - av = av + av - av \iff av = 0$.

If $v = 0$, we can do a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

If $a=0$ it's obvious.

Let $a\neq0$.

Thus, $$a^{-1}(a\vec{v})=a^{-1}\vec{0}$$ or
$$(a^{-1}a)\vec{v}=\vec{0}$$ or
$$1\vec{v}=\vec{0}$$ or
$$\vec{v}=\vec{0}.$$
done!